# if i use android 4.1.2 (API 16) Android SDK will my apps work on Android 2.3

Tags: android, sdk

if i use android 4.1.2 (API 16) Android SDK will my apps work on Android 2.3 phones. i have downloaded android 4.1.2 sdk tools and other packages.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the minimum SDK attribute in your manifest to 2.3 to ensure you app will work on earlier versions of the OS.

Your app will work fine, assuming you are not using any API calls from a later version.

The Android Dev team suggests you always compile against the newest version you can support.  So, you are on the right track.

So bottom line, you are on the right track, just make sure to test your app against a 2.3.3 version of the emulator to ensure you are not using any un-supported API calls.

Answer (score 0):

No, if your minimum sdk version is 16 it wont work on that android version.
if you want it to work on that specific version then set the minimum sdk version to 9. You can change this in the apps manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
/>
```

If you are getting errors probably saying "This code uses the minimum sdk to be api 16 or higher"
find alternate ways to modify the code for older android phones. If that does not work then dont support old version of android maybe.