# How can I prevent the project from using a specific Android API?

Tags: android, android-studio, static-analysis

In a project with API 16 compatibility I've been using vector drawables with `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` which is of course incorrect and crashes in old devices, needing to be [replaced by AppCompatResources instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38507596/172690). I have removed all method calls, but how can I prevent them from appearing again in case of distraction?

Note that the API is not deprecated, can a *good* API be somehow flagged as error in a project? The `minSdkVersion` is set to 16 and `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 27, the `ContextCompat.getDrawable` API is for all purposes available on any API level, but fails when used with vector drawables, so I want to prevent during compilation its usage in favor of `AppCompatResources`.

Comment: similar question was answered [here][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343899/if-i-use-android-4-1-2-api-16-android-sdk-will-my-apps-work-on-android-2-3

Comment: @PaEbou doesn't have anything to do

Comment: I think we have no control for that but just to write in that way since you haven't restricted its max and min api version

Comment: Min/max API versions are correctly set, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Android Studio indicates when you're trying to use a method whose minimum API level is higher than your minimum project API level. I don't think is a good idea try to flag as error some API, as you would have to mark or delete the whole android.support.v4 API entry from your Gradle file (it could be an option if you're not interested in keeping it). Just make sure you use the app compat v7 one when you import the package and you're done :)

Comment: The API is not marked due to minimum levels since it works when you don't pass it a vector drawable.